# Show sub category listing on category page in Porto theme Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I tried to show Sub category listing on category page in Porto theme, but nothing works in Magento. I also tried this [tutorial](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html#gref).

Comment: You are expected to post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I gave the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to `app/design/frontend/theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`.

This is your category listing page.

Here you can put the code

```
 <?php

  $currCategoryId = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currCategoryId);
                  $subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
                if(count($subcategories)>0){ 
                         $count=1; 
                    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                        $category1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcategory->getId());
                        $subcategories1 = $category1->getChildrenCategories();
                        echo $subcategory->getName()."<br/>";
                        if(count($subcategories1)>0){ 

                            foreach ($subcategories1 as $thirdLevelCategory) {
                                echo "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
                                echo $thirdLevelCategory->getName()."<br/>";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }   
   ?>
```

Note: It's better to create a block and load your data from the block or you can create a helper in your module and use that in your template.

Comment: Can u tell where i have to put this piece or how can i make it work

Comment: You want the subcategories of a particular category to be listed in Category listing page right ?

Comment: I want sub categories in category page instead of product pagr